# Update Stored Procedure in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I tried to change the user password using a stored procedure.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult ChangeMyPassword(MyModel model)
{
    int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);
    context.sp_ChangePassword(UserId, model.NewPassword);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return view();
}
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
USE [CRM_DEMO]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ChangePassword]
@Id int ,
@NewPassword Varchar(50)
AS
Update UserTable
set
UserPassword = @NewPassword 
WHERE UserId= @Id
```

It works; however, the password does not change in the database. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I see a space in the key UserId

```
int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId "]);
                                            ^
```

Can you verify if you are actually passing the userid value to the stored procedure. If not would not update and would not be an error to update no rows.

Comment: Hmm. Don't see anything else wrong. Can you quickly put a stop at the "context.sp_ChangePassword(UserId, model.NewPassword)" and just check both values?

Comment: İ think problem is on database side.There is no problem in controller side.

Comment: Then call the procedure from the database and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
USE [CRM_DEMO]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ChangePassword]
(
@Id int ,
@NewPassword Varchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
   UPDATE UserTable
   SET UserPassword = @NewPassword 
   WHERE UserId= @Id
END
```